# How to return a 404 when drf returns empty queryset using ListAPIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class listapiview(ListAPIView):

    queryset = testobj.objects.all()
    serializer_class = testobjSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = testobj.objects.all()
        build_id = self.request.query_params.get('id', None)
        if id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(id=id)
        return queryset
```

I just rewrote some views from APIView to ListAPIView and it broke some of my unittests because an empty queryset still returns a 200.  I would like to figure out the best way to return a 404 (or whatever the appropriate error code would be in this) using my example.

I tried adding:

```
if queryset:
    return queryset
else:
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

But received a paginator error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()
```

Comment: why you want 404 on list view ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I do tbh, what I am trying to accomplish is just to NOT return a 200 success if queryset is empty...

Comment: Well, a `get_queryset` function is expecting a `queryset` not a `Response`. If you'd like to incorporate this, you can raise an exception just like suggested by one of the answers.

Answer (score 10):

raise exception instead of returning `Response`

django rest framework has multiple predefined exceptions such as `NotFound` exception, in their `exception` module. You can add it by importing it from the exception

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import NotFound
```

and modify your `get_queryset` logic by the following code

```
if queryset:
    return queryset
else:
    raise NotFound()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use

`return    HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>Page not found</h1>')`

Sorry for formatting, on mobile